# Приходит пустая переменная

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Исмпользую [storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). Считываю данные из `inputs` результаты и вывожу в консоль для проверка, тут все хорошо:

```
this.storage.set(this.keyPulseDate, inputs['date']).then((valDate) => {
  console.log('date', valDate);
});
this.storage.set(this.keyPulseTime, inputs['time']).then((valTime) => {
  console.log('time', valTime);
});
this.storage.set(this.keyPulseCurrect, inputs['currect']).then((valCurrect) => {
  console.log('currect', valCurrect);
});
```

Потом записываю их в `items`:

```
  items: any = {
    'day': [
      {
        name: 'День',
        periud: this.storage.get(this.keyPulseTime),
        param: this.storage.get(this.keyPulseCurrect)
      }
    ],
    'week': [
      {
        name: 'Неделя',
        period: ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'],
        param: [11, 1, 5, 18, 15, 10, 1]
      }
    ]
}
```

После хочу использую `items` в графике:

```
    this.ctx = document.getElementById('myChartDiogram');
    this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.items[this.data][0].period,
        datasets: [{
          data: this.items[this.data][0].param,
          borderColor: '#488aff',
          fill: false,
          borderWidth: 3
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Что приходит:

```
0:
name: "День"
param: t {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: undefined}
periud: t {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: undefined}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Но данные приходят пустые. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

`this.storage.get` - тоже возвращает промис.

```
items: any = {
  'day': [
    {
      name: 'День',
      periud: null; // this.storage.get(this.keyPulseTime),
      param: null;  // this.storage.get(this.keyPulseCurrect)
    }
  ],
  ...
}

this.storage.get(this.keyPulseTime).then(val => items.day[0].periud = val);
this.storage.get(this.keyPulseCurrect).then(val => items.day[0].param = val);
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, `this.storage.get(this.keyPulseTime)` срабатывает до того, как `this.storage.set` успеет записать данные? Что показывает промежуточный вывод консоли после записи данных в items? Ну и `periud: this.storage.geе...` наверное, `periоd: this.storage.get...`